# Why can't I see contents of /storage

Tags: android, android-storage

If we use the Android APIs to get the external storage directory, we get something like, `/storage/emulated/0`. If I run a recursive traversal on the same, I get a list of all the files and folders inside listed.

So, I thought of running the traversal on `/storage` thinking it would return all the public directories present. But, on running the same, I get a null list of Files inside it. For listing the files/folders, i have used the API: `File.listFiles()`

Why is this happening and how can I get a list of all publicly accessible files/folders on all the storages on Android?

Comment: What kind of device? Android version?

Comment: Cannot confirm this. Normally /storage/emulated is not readable. But /storage is and only contains directories. No files. Most of those directories are not accessable. And the 0 dir will not be listed.

Comment: Try File.list();

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below function for getting all the files of sdcard and its folder, subfolders. this works fine for me.

```
//A recursive function to list files of all folders and subfolders of SD Card
private void getAllFilesOfDir(File directory) {
    Log.d("Spinner", "Directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

    final File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    if ( files != null ) {
        for ( File file : files ) {
            if ( file != null ) {
                if ( file.isDirectory() ) {  // it is a folder...
                    getAllFilesOfDir(file);
                }
                else {  // it is a file...
                    Log.d("Spinner", "File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                    allFileNameString.add(file.getName());
                    allFilePathString.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are you sure you gave correct path of sdcard storage directory, as the function call over here?

```
getAllFilesOfDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

And try debugging inside the function, what goes wrong?